# Laravel send image with json_encode

Tags: php, laravel

I'm an android developer and I want to use Laravel framework to use as a web service for my application in android. In android I need to receive data with text and an image. In laravel I don't know how to send the image with `json_encode`. For example in this simple code below I can simply send data from laravel with `json_encode` :

```
Route::post('/android', function () {
    echo json_encode(array(
        '1'=>'hello',
        '2'=>'my image',
        '3'=>'IMAGE',
    ));
});
```

`3` key must be an image. Must I send the image in base64?

Answer (score 4):

For starters you can use `Response::json` instead of `json_encode`. And to  return the image you can indeed encode it using base64 like so:

```
Route::post('/android', function ()
{
    return Response::json(array(
        '1' => 'hello',
        '2' => 'my image',
        '3' => base64_encode(File::get('/path/to/image.jpg'))
    ));
});
```

`File::get` will return the file contents as a string and `base64_encode` will encode it. Also, unless you specifically need those exact array indexes (`1`, `2`, `3`), you can either remove them altogether, or use some more readable names such as `message`, `filename` and `content`.

Answer (score 2):

you can use php's **base64_encode** on server side and decode on android device
make sure image exists at specified location

```
Route::any('/android', function () {
     $localFileName  = public_path().'/uploads/php.png';
     $fileData = file_get_contents($localFileName);
     $ImgfileEncode = base64_encode($fileData);

    echo json_encode(array(
        'message'=>'hello',
        'image_name'=>'php.png',
        'image'=>$ImgfileEncode,
    )); exit;
});
```